# in vue.js; it's useless to toggle with the attribute 'readonly' of textarea in true or false;

Tags: html, vue.js

**what i want to do is:**

1. The textarea can be edited when dblclick the textarea;
2. The textarea can't be edited when blur;

But now ,it's useless whatever I toggle with the state of 'readonly' attribute;

[codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/4qr8vvm35x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input
    v-model="textVal"
    :rows="rows"
    :readonly="status"
    :autoHeight="autoHeight"
    class="textMsg"
    @input="inputing"
    @blur="blur"
  ></input>
  <button @click="dblclick">Test</button>
```

Hello, I read your example, the code is no problem, the reason for the unexpected effect is the conflict between the ondbclick event and the onblur event. Well, I am sorry that I can't explain this. But my solution is to add a click event to the button to change the value of the text field. Others are unchanged.

Checking the information is the priority of the event. So you can look at this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer; but it's not friendly to add a button to do that in my project；

Comment: You should take a note on the code above. DoubleClick events on the input fields, should not be a practice. Have you ever seen app like that? Um.. Just implement simple `Edit` button.

Comment: thanks all of your advice; I have had want to edit that just like in photoshop or svgEditor; now,I will add a button above of the textarea;